# How to sum the data from two tables sql

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, case

I have result set from 2 tables

Table1

---

```
      Mediaid  FilteredDocsCount FileSize
        2000     5                  20
        3000     2                  25
```

Table2

---

```
        Mediaid   FilteredDocsCount  FileSize
         2000        3                  50
         2001        4                  20
         2005        2                  23
         3000        3                  22
```

My goal is to add the filteredDocsCount and filesize from these tables. I am expecting the following result:

```
    Mediaid   FilteredDocsCount  Filesize
     2000        8                  70
     2001        4                  20
     2005        2                  23
     3000        5                  47
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A straightforward union, grouped by mediaid should do the trick

```
select mediaid, sum(FilteredDocsCount ), sum(filesize)
from 
(select *
from table1 tb1
union all 
select *
from table2) sub
group by mediaid
```

Check out how it works in [this Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/c958f9/2)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an outer join:

```
select t2.mediaid, t2.FilteredDocsCount + coalesce(t1.FilteredDocsCount, 0),
       t2.filesize + coalesce(t1.filesize, 0)
from table2 t2 left join
     table1 t1
     on t2.mediaid = t1.mediaid
```

Comment: Downvotes on correct answers just make the site look bad.

Comment: The above query returned  more counts for the medias that are repeated in both the tables.

Comment: @ppokh . . . The sample data has no examples of media ids repeated in the tables.  There is no reason to think that is an issue based on the question.